# move constructor along copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor

ist is possible to have a copy constructor implemented along with a move constructor? If I would have the following abstract class structure:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
  public:
    A<T>();
    A<T>(const& T);
    A<T>(T&&);
  // ...
}
```

1. Is it possible to have both, copy - and move constructor
2. How would a call of both of them look like? Is there a special syntax?
3. How is the compiler differing between both calls?

Comment: Yes you can have both defined, they are different functions....

Comment: Obviously they are but is the function call the same? `A<T> a(some_other_A)

Comment: Yes but look at the *arguments*. The copy constructor takes a `const` reference, and the move constructor takes an rvalue (temporary) reference